Does Richardson Extrapolation do anything else than increasing the speed of convergence?
I feel like I am conceptually confused about the point of Richardson Extrapolation. How I understood it, is that if we have some function $\mathcal{A}(h)$ that approximates $\alpha_0$, and can be expanded as:$$\mathcal{A}(n)=\alpha_0+\sum_{i=1}^k{\alpha_i}h^i + \mathcal{R}_{k+1}(h).$$
Then we can construct an iterative algorithm that in essence calculates $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\mathcal{A}(h)$ but with a much better rate of convergence than just taking $h\rightarrow 0$(and since we can't really take like $h=10^{-1000}$ because of computational stuff). But my confusion stems from this post Numerical integral with Richardson extrapolation. The answer there says that "applying Richardson extrapolation to the trapezoidal quadrature method gives Simpson's method.". I thought that all that Richardson extrapolation did was increase the rate of convergence? And not actually somehow give a different method (different as in an already existing one)? Like Romberg integration is essentially an iterative algorithm to calculate the composite trapezoidal rule quickly? Or am I missing something

Oh, so essentially $\mathcal{A}{m,0}$ are the "original" schemes with decreasing $h$, while all other $\mathcal{A}{m,q}$ are iteratively genenerated new schemes(which might or might not be other common ones), where all they have in common is that they are supposed to converge to the same value with their errors dependant on the corresponding iterations. Think i got it

@jaceks123 : Exactly that. And with the lower-order methods it is almost sure that they have also been derived via other means and got a name that way. The extrapolation of Simpson also has a name, the higher order methods not, as far as I know. The same goes for the Newton method that has a higher order method in the Halley method and a series of unnamed higher-order methods that some obscure tech-report named Householder methods. (Which I transcribed into wikipedia and thus into the wider world. No other older source for the name exists. The sequence of methods was described several times.)
